# Running yum update in fedora 21 makes a very large image

Tags: docker

I have the fedora 21 image pulled,

```
fedora              21                  834629358fe2        5 weeks ago         250.2 MB
```

I create a Dockerfile

```
from fedora:21
maintainer ...
run yum -y update
```

Then I do,

```
sudo docker build -t eric/fedora:21 .
```

But the size of this image is very large, about 650MB ,

```
eric/fedora         21                  50cbf024d8f4        16 seconds ago      658.8 MB
```

Is this OK, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As first attempt, it is good practice removing the `yum` cache (or any cache system, as apt) in your Docker image. In case of `yum` you can use `yum clean all`.

If it doesn't fix the issue, you can run an instance of fedora:21 container, run `yum update` manually, and check why it increases so much its size. Maybe there are some missing packages from fedora image that are installed when you run yum update (tip: to check easily all the files changed in the container you can use `docker diff`).

Comment: Is your Dockerfile in a directory with a lot of files ? That could explain it.